# Can the code under iOSPort be edited in a CN1 application?

Tags: codenameone

I know how to debug and modify CodenameOne source in an app. That is described [here](https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i-debug-into-codename-one-source-modify-it-contribute-it-back.html)

Can I do the same for the code under iOSPort? I am interested in testing a modified version of  Ports/iOSPort/nativeSources/CodenameOne_GLAppDelegate.m. using a build hint to append code to the delegate is not an option since what I need to test is a change within an existing method.
I think a recent update broke something in it but the ticket I raised on GitHub isn't being replied to, so I'd like to see if I can propose a fix myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use include source the full iOS port is included into the source and you can debug directly into the port. You can just copy and paste your changes into there and then debug these changes. Then copy and paste it back.

That's how we test changes to the port.

Comment: So I don't have a mac and was wondering if there was a way for me to build a final ipa file with a modified port. This would be my closest approximation to debugging without a mac. I also need to debug ios push registration which atm is broken and this can't be debugged I think. I do have a MacInCloud with xCode, would that be enough to make a modified ipa file with a changed port?

Comment: No. You need a Mac for that. You can't replace the builtin Codename One implementation or port when sending a build.